# VSCode timeout error when download dotnet runtime v7.0.9

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My vscode when want to download dotnet runtime v7.0.9 get error time out

> Downloading the .NET Runtime.
> Downloading .NET version(s) 7.0.9 .......................................................................................................................... Error!
> Failed to download .NET 7.0.9:
> .NET installation timed out.
>
> Error!
> .NET Acquisition Failed: Installation failed: Error: .NET installation timed out.

and intelligence of C# doesnot work and my C# output is

> [Error - 2:06:46 AM] Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create connection to server.
> Error: Could not resolve the dotnet path!
> at t.DotnetRuntimeExtensionResolver. (c:\Users\Jaam-e-Jam.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-2.0.249-win32-x64\dist\extension.js:2:1009858)
> at Generator.next ()
> at s (c:\Users\Jaam-e-Jam.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-2.0.249-win32-x64\dist\extension.js:2:1008463)

I Search the net and I set it to setting.json file

```
    "dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath": [
        {
            "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csdevkit",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
        },
        {
            "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.vscodeintellicode-csharp",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
        },
        {
            "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
        },
        {
            "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
        }
    ]
```

but for each project i must to set it!
How can i fix it?

Comment: Please edit `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath": [
        {
            "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csdevkit",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
        },
        {
            "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.vscodeintellicode-csharp",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
        },
        {
            "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
        },
        {
            "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
        }
    ]
```

Above code is usefull and is answer but we need write it in this Address

```
%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
```

Thanks a lot from @LexLi